# why wont my while loop break

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

I can not figure out why my while loop won't break and it just keeps running I have tries making Lc 10 and I tried return but nothing will end the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BirthdayReminder
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] BDay = new String[10];
      String[] friend = new String[10];
      int Lc = 0;
      String i;

      while(Lc < 10) {
            System.out.println("enter a friends name or zzz to quit");
            i = input.nextLine();
            if(i == "zzz") { 
                break;
            }
            else if(i != "zzz"){
            friend[Lc] = i;
            System.out.println("enter their birthday.");
            i = input.nextLine();
            BDay[Lc] = i;
            Lc++;
            return;
            }
      }
      System.out.println("hi");

   }
```

}

Comment: Java basics, this will return always false: `i == "zzz"`. It should be instead `"zzz".equals(i)`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz It won't *always* return false.

Comment: In this case, how can the variable `i` and the anonymous object "zzz" be the same object?

Comment: Thank you for the help the "zzz".equals(i) worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check string equality using `equals()`, not `==`. Neither block of code inside the `if` is getting entered, so `Lc` is never incremented.